# How to read error message as a string from error object on Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling

For example I just got this error:

```
{ Error: There was an error sending your trade offer. We were unable to contact the game's item server. The game's item server may be down or Steam may be experiencing temporary connectivity issues. Please try again later.
    at Object.exports.makeAnError (C:\Some\Boring\Route\node_modules\steam-tradeoffer-manager\lib\helpers.js:17:12)
    at SteamCommunity.manager._community.httpRequestPost...
```

How do I get just the "There was an error sending your trade offer..." part so I can later send it back to the client?

Comment: Try JSON.parse()

Comment: It's a bit strange, that you have `{` at the beginning. If it's a typical instance of Error then use @Ryan's solution. If `error.message` for some reason contains JSON and `Error` is a key, then use`JSON.parse(error.message).Error` as @Avihay suggested to extract the error

Comment: @Dmitry: The `{` is formatting from e.g. `console.log('%o', new Error())`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It’s in the `message` property.

```js
let error = new Error('example');
console.log(error.message);
```

See also [the string representation of errors per ECMAScript](https://es5.github.io/#x15.11.4.4).

Answer (score 12):

My `err.message` is null. I used `err.toString()` 
It's saved my ass.